# importing python file class instead from sibling directory instead of python module with same name

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a following directory structure

```
own_lib/
    directory_a/
        alib.py

test/
    b.py
```

In *b.py* I have something like this for importing *alib.py*

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../own_lib/directory_a/'))
from alib import a_func
```

But my problem is that I have python module with same name *alib* installed in my system. Thus *b.py* always imports installed module rather than *alib.py* from sibling directory. If *b.py* and *alib.py* are in same directory then it works fine but not if they are in different directories in spite of using *sys.path.append*. I can't uninstall this module neither change the name of *alib.py*. What will be the best possible solution for resolving this 
error?

Comment: Why not make `own_lib` a package so that you can do `from own_lib import alib` or `from own_lib.directory_a import alib`?

Comment: Due to certain restriction I can't make own_lib package neither uninstall already existing module. I have to use it as file.